# Update database scheme in Sulu cms

Tags: php, database, sulu

I have a table `categories` and I need to add one additional row named `sort order`. Can I do this in Symfony way like `doctrine:schema:update` or something like this or I need to do it in another way?

Comment: is this a custom table/entity?

Comment: yes. there is a folder named 'project-build' with db.sql file inside which creates tables for project.

Comment: and how will this sql file be imported? doctrine:schema:update can only handle doctrine entities

Comment: I know it, but the question is does Sulu has something like this doctrine:schema:update to updating existing tables ?

Comment: we dont have any built in tools for this. we relly on the tools of symfony and doctrine for this task